# Vuex update state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, promise, vuex

When I'm calling a Vuex action and perform an axios request, it's not updating all my localStorage item, it's very strange.

My axios request could return objects or an empty collection and I would like to update all the time my `userDailyFoods` item. I console log my mutation and getter and it works but for the update of the localStorage item it's bugging. Sometimes I get the result, sometimes not.

What am I doing wrong ?

action:

```js
updateUserDailyFoods(context, data) {
  let date = data.data
  if (date) {
    axios.get(`/user/daily/food/${context.getters.user.id}/${date}/`).then(r => {
      context.commit('userDailyFoods', {
        userDailyFoods: r.data.data
      });
      localStorage.setItem('userDailyFoods', JSON.stringify(r.data.data));
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('userDailyFoods'));
}
```

mutation:

```
userDailyFoods (state, payload) {
  if(payload) {
    state.userDailyFoods = payload.userDailyFoods
  }
},
```

getter:

```
userDailyFoods(state){
  return state.userDailyFoods
}
```

state:

```
userDailyFoods: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDailyFoods')) || [],
```

> UPDATED

when i go to my view component

```js
computed: {
  userDailyFoods() {
    return this.$store.state.userDailyFoods
  },
}
```

and I console log my action:

```
console.log(this.userDailyFoods)
```

then the result is updated after two clicks, not only one.

```js
getDaySelected(day) {
  var day = moment(day).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  this.$store.dispatch('updateUserDailyFoods', {
    data: day
  })
  console.log(this.userDailyFoods)
  this.$parent.$data.foods = this.userDailyFoods
}
```

Comment: The log is in the sync flow, at which time the async operation may or may not be finished.  Log from inside the `then` block instead.  As an aside, there is no need for that `getter`, which you can think of as a `computed` that isn't computing anything.

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you show me your solution ? will be more explicit for me @Dan

Comment: I still don't know what exactly isn't working. Is your localStorage always empty? Is your Vuex store always empty?

Comment: i need to click two times to the action to get the localStorage.getItem('userDailyFoods') updated with the collection of data i don't know why;

Comment: i have another action who don't need axios call and it's work perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer as requested) The value is probably being set in localStorage every time, but you're trying to log it before the async Axios operation has completed.  Move the `console.log` into the `then` block:

```
.then(r => {
    context.commit('userDailyFoods', {userDailyFoods: r.data.data});
    localStorage.setItem('userDailyFoods', JSON.stringify(r.data.data));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('userDailyFoods'));
})
```

Axios (and AJAX in general) is asynchronous which means that the operation begins separately from the normal synchronous flow of code.  After it begins, program execution immediately resumes, often before the async operation is complete.  At the time you are logging to the console, there is no guarantee that this async promise is resolved yet.

As an aside, there is no need for that getter, which you can think of as a computed that isn't computing anything.

Comment: Thats works @dan when i put the console log inside the response but when it console.log inside my component i have the same effect as before. it's need two times before updating correctly (i updated the post)

Comment: That means you are making the same mistake in your component.  You can't log to the console until the async operation is finished (by using a `then` block).

Comment: first console log return [__ob__: Observer] with nothing the second click return [{…}, __ob__: Observer] with the collection data

Comment: how i could achieve this in my component ?

Comment: It only takes 1 click to set the storage, but you are trying to log it before it's finished.  Instead of trying to log it in the console, try using the `userDailyFoods` computed in the template, and you will probably see that it renders when it is finished loading.

Comment: i need to assign the parent data object with the result of the action in vuex so using in the template will be not the solution in my case i guess. this.$parent.$data.foods = this.userDailyFoods

Comment: Instead of using `this.$parent` (bad pattern), give the parent access to the Vuex `userDailyFoods` state.  That is the purpose of Vuex, so that you don't have to pass data between components.

Comment: so i will need to refresh the page in order to display the changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207039/discussion-between-dan-and-mathieu-mourareau).

Comment: i used this to update the value of the parent without reloading the page