# Feathersjs-Vuex: how to update a vuex state from sql query

Tags: vuex, feathersjs

For a background to this question, i recommend read the thread below:

- [vuex-update-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021983/vuex-update-state)

I will show the contexts of my question in backend and frontend sides:

#### Backend

- a feathersjs server;
- the server has 3 services: users, grades and students;
- the database adapter used is [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html) for a postgresql database.

#### Frontend

1. A server side rendering build in nuxt with vuetify;
2. A [feathersjs-vuex](https://vuex.feathersjs.com/service-plugin.html#setup) to manage states
3. the '/profile' page (frontend) request for an authenticated user ('/users' in backend)
4. the '/grades' page (frontend) request a query for all grades that belongs to the authenticated user ('/grades' in backend)
5. the '/students' page (frontend) request a query for all students that belongs to any grades of an authenticated user ('/students' in backend)

So, my specific question is about the item 5 of frontend context. With the following code, I can retrieve *"all students that belongs to any grades of an authenticated user"*, but the computed property `students` return an empty array:

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState('students', { areStudentsLoading: 'isFindPending' }),
    ...mapGetters('students', { findStudentsInStore: 'find' }),
    query () {
      return {
        query: {
          $sort: {
            first_name: 1,
            last_name: 1
          },
          $select: ['first_name', 'last_name'],
          include: [{
            model: 'grades',
            where: {
              userUuid: this.$store.state.auth.user.uuid
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    computed () {
      return this.findStudentsInStore(this.query).data
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.findStudents(this.query)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('students', { findStudents: 'find' })
  }
}
</script>
```

So, the `findStudents` is a AJAX request, and in the [commented thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021983/vuex-update-state) someone reply:

> Axios (and AJAX in general) is asynchronous which means that the operation begins separately from the normal synchronous flow of code. After it begins, program execution immediately resumes, often before the async operation is complete. At the time you are logging to the console, there is no guarantee that this async promise is resolved yet.

> As an aside, there is no need for that getter, which you can think of as a computed that isn't computing anything.

So i tested the following code, where i substituted the computed property *students* for a *student data*, and it worked:

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    query () {
      return {
        query: {
          $sort: {
            first_name: 1,
            last_name: 1
          },
          $select: ['first_name', 'last_name'],
          include: [{
            model: 'grades',
            where: {
              userUuid: this.$store.state.auth.user.uuid
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  data () {
    return { students: [] }
  },
  created () {
    this.findStudents(this.query).then((response) => {
      this.students = response.data
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('students', { findStudents: 'find' })
  }
}
</script>
```

So, my question is: there is a way to update the state os students in store or i should rely on the last approach?

Answer (score 0):

With some experiences in coding, i found a solution. I hope that it helps someone with similar problems.

1. First, the source of problem was in service hook that parses the eager loading query.
2. Second, i substituted `...mapGetters('students', { findStudents: 'find' })`.

### Backend: fixing service hook with eager loading

I noted that performance in parsing query is important. I was doing a `for loop` in each element of `include` paramm, and that delayed the reponse.

So, i optmized the eager loading hook with this in server:

#### src/eager_loading.js

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const eager_loading = function() {
  return async function (context) {
    if (context.params.query && context.params.query.include) {
      console.log(context.params.query);
      context.params.sequelize = {
        include: _.map(context.params.query.include, function(query) {
          console.log (query);
          return _.update(query, 'model', function(m) {
            return context.app.service(m).Model;
          });
        })
      };
      delete context.params.query.include;
    }
    return context;
  }
};

module.exports = eager_loading;
```

#### src/app.hooks.js

```
// Application hooks that run for every service
const eager_loading = require('./eager_loading');

module.exports = {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [
      eager_loading()
    ],
    get: [],
  },
  // etc...
```

### Frontend: substitute find getter to list getter

The time of response, in client side, was faster. I don't have numerical measurement values, but it was visually noticeable on Vue.devtools and the response was updated in vuex getters.

#### pages/students/index.vue

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  filters: {
    complete_name (student) {
      return `${student.first_name} ${student.last_name}`
    },
    grade (student) {
      return student['grade.grade']
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('students', { areStudentsLoading: 'isFindPending' }),
    ...mapGetters('students', { listStudentsInStore: 'list' }),
    query () {
      return {
        query: {
          $sort: {
            first_name: 1,
            last_name: 1
          },
          $select: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'uuid'],
          include: [{
            model: 'grades',
            attributes: ['grade'],
            where: {
              userUuid: this.$store.state.auth.user.uuid
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    },
    students () {
      return this.listStudentsInStore
    },
    loading () {
      return this.areStudentsLoading
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.findStudents(this.query)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('students', { findStudents: 'find' })
  }
}
</script>
```